# c++ debug '<<' no operator found

Tags: c++, debugging

I am trying to run the following code on c++ but keep geting error. Can anyone solve it for me please.
the error message from c++ says:

> Error 6   error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a
>   right-hand operand of type 'MVector'

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cmath>
 #ifndef MVECTOR_H // the 'include guard'
 #define MVECTOR_H // see C++ Primer Sec. 2.9.2
 #include <vector>
 #include <string>
 #include <fstream>

 class MVector
 {
 public:
     // constructors
     MVector() {}
     explicit MVector(int n) : v(n) {}
     MVector(int n, double x) : v(n, x) {}

     void push_back(double x)
     {
         v.push_back(x);
     }

     double AV()
     {
         double sum = 0.0, average = 0.0;
         for (double i = 0; i<v.size(); i++)
         {
             sum += v[i];
         }
         average = sum / v.size();
         return average;
     }

     MVector RunningAverage(int m, int p)
     {
         MVector movingaverage(v.size() - m - p - 1);
         for (int i = m; i < v.size() - p; i++)
         {
             double sum = 0.0;
             if ((i + p < v.size()))
             {
                 for (int j = i - m; j <= i + p; j++)
                 {
                     sum += v[j];
                     movingaverage[i - m] = sum / (m + p + 1);
                 }
             }
         }
         return movingaverage; // Edit by jpo38
    }

    // access element (lvalue)
    double &operator[](int index) { return v[index]; }
    // access element (rvalue)
    double operator[](int index) const { return v[index]; }
    int size() const { return v.size(); } // number of elements

private:
    std::vector<double> v;
};
#endif

int main()
{
    using namespace std; 
    // create an MVector
    MVector x;
    // add elements to the vector
    x.push_back(1.3);
    x.push_back(3.5);
    x.push_back(3.0);
    x.push_back(2.0);
    // x now contains 1.3 and 3.5
    // print x
    std::cout << " x:= ( ";
    for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
        std::cout << x[i] << " ";
    std::cout << ")\n";
    std::cout << x.RunningAverage(0, 1.0) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to print with `std::cout << x.RunningAverage(0, 1.0) << endl;`? Are you aware that `x.RunningAverage(0, 1.0)` returns `MVector`?

Comment: `x.RunningAverage(0, 1.0) ` returns a `MVector` (actually there is no return statement, but that's the signature of it)

Comment: i am trying to return the moving average

Comment: @Shawn, if you're trying to return it, just add a return statement....;-) I edited the OP and added the `return movingaverage;`

Comment: @jpo38 thank you very much. i did try put the operator below my function but it's still not working

Comment: Operator has to be declared after the class (in the header file) or directly in the file containing the `main` function (just before the `main` function). It must work.

Comment: @jpo38 i tried to put it above "int main()" but it's still not working

Comment: You must be doing it wrong. It compiles and work: http://cpp.sh/7afyi

Answer (score 1):

`x.RunningAverage(0, 1.0)` returns a `MVector` that cannot be sent to `std::cout`, unless you declare the `operator<<` taking a `MVector` as parameter.

Alternatively, you can replace:

```
std::cout << x.RunningAverage(0, 1.0) << endl;
```

By:

```
MVector av = x.RunningAverage(0, 1.0);
for (int i = 0; i < av.size(); i++)
    std::cout << av[i] << " ";
```

Or, declare the operator:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const MVector& b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++)
        out << b[i] << " ";
    return out;
}
```

And then `std::cout << x.RunningAverage(0, 1.0) << std::endl;` will work.

And you can then also replace, in your `main` function:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
    std::cout << x[i] << " ";
```

By:

```
std::cout << x;
```

Live demo: http://cpp.sh/7afyi

Answer (score 0):

You haven't overloaded `operator<<` for `MVector`.

You can do that with:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, MVector const& vec)
{
    // use "output << …;" to do printing
    return output;
}
```